# Can't download images with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm kinda new to Python. I want to download and rescale many images at once so I can use them as negative samples to train a haar cascade. Maybe I mixed some python 3.0 code in mine. I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/!Servici/Python/Remake/negative_grab.py", line 26, in <module> store_raw_images()
File "D:/!Servici/Python/Remake/negative_grab.py", line 7, in store_raw_images
neg_image_urls = urllib2.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4837: ordinal not in range(128)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

```
import urllib2
import cv2
import os

def store_raw_images():
    neg_images_link = 'http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n04335209'
    neg_image_urls = urllib2.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()

    if not os.path.exists('neg_sample'):
        os.makedirs('neg_samples')

    pic_num = 1

    for i in neg_image_urls.split('\n'):
        try:
            print(i)
            urllib2.urlretrieve(i, "neg/"+str(pic_num)+'.jpg')
            img = cv2.imread("neg/"+str(pic_num)+'.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            resize_image = cv2.resize(img, (100,100))
            cv2.imwrite(("neg/")+str(pic_num)+'.jpg', resize_image)
            pic_num += 1

        except Exception as e:
            print (str(e))

    store_raw_images()
```

Comment: provide the full stack trace please

Comment: .. and fix the indentation if your code sample (the body of `store_raw_images`)

Answer (score 0):

Your decode is running into errors. Try with `decode('utf-8')`